# File transfer in recovery mode

Tags: macos, hard-drive, recovery

My MacOS (10.13) would not boot normally. So I restarted it into recovery mode. Then connected an external HDD, reformatted it to APFS, and started `cp -r /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD /Volumes/External_HDD`

After 3 hours, I decided to quit the task and find out why it is taking so long. The Macintosh HD directory contains 395GB. The external drive contains 550GB (and this is just half of the files). Per this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364999/file-size-changes-when-using-cp), sometimes "sparseness" fails. Is there a faster alternative to cp in this case?

Comment: Do you really need to copy all files or would the content of `/Users` be enough?

Comment: Depends on how long it takes. I wasnt expecting this to take so long. So I guess, /Users is enough. But is cp the most straightforward way?

Comment: Speed is limited by your disks and the wire between them. I usually use rsync because it is restartable, ditto might also be an option.